# Well-definedness of a Function from a Quotient Set to the Cartesian Product of Two Quotients Sets

Tags: set-theory, equivalence-relations

Recently, I have been studying functions whose domain and codomain are both quotient sets (i.e. sets of equivalence classes). I discovered how it is important to check that such a 'mapping' is well-defined in such circumstances. I was wondering what would happen if the codomain was the Cartesian product of two quotient sets instead. Can you explain the difference between checking this and checking when the codomain is a quotient set? What is the logic behind these differences? Let me be more explicit:

> Let $S$ and $T$ be sets, and $\sim_{S}$, $\sim_{T}$, and $\sim_{S
>  \times T}$ be equivalence relations on $S$, $T$ and $S \times T$,
> respectively. Show that the 'mapping' $f: \dfrac{S\times T}{\sim_{S
>  \times T}} \to \dfrac{S}{\sim_S} \times \dfrac{T}{\sim_T}$ is
> well-defined.

I know that strategy used in the case where $f : \dfrac{S}{\sim_{S}} \to \dfrac{T}{\sim_T}$
would be to define a function $F: S \to T$ such that $f(\left[ x\right]) = \left[F(x)\right]$ and prove that if $x \sim_S y$ then $F(x) \sim_T F(x)$. How would one have to adapt the strategy to prove the above? What are the reason for that specific adaption?

Comment: The same way. Note that a map into $A\times B$ is equivalent to a pair of maps, one into $A$ and one into $B$; so you can handle each coordinate separately. Or you can verify that if you take $\sim_S\times \sim_T$ you get an equivalence relation on $S\times T$, and that there is a natural bijection $(S/\sim_S)\times (T/\sim_T) \leftrightarrow (S\times T)/(\sim_S\times\sim_T)$ by mapping $([s]_{\sim_S},[t]_{\sim_T})$ to $[(s,t)]_{\sim_S\times\sim_T}$.

Comment: And how would you verify that the bijection you mentioned is well-defined?

Comment: The usual way: if $[s]=[s']$ and ${t]=[t']$, then $[(s,t)] = [(s',t')]$. The fact that the target is a quotient makes no difference, except that the equality of images may require the use of the equivalence relation.